# How to delete a file from App_Data folder in asp.net mvc 3 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, file-upload

I read an excel file from the user using

```
 <input type="file" name="file" />
```

send it to the controller and store it in App_Data folder. I read that file. After I am done I wish to delete the file from App_Data folder. How do I do that?
This is how I store it.

```
    public ActionResult importFile1(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
File.Delete("~/App_Data/uploads/myfile.xls");
```

After processing the file has finished?

Answer (score 1):

Another way for deleting file is:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("~/App_Data/uploads/image.jpg");
file.Delete();
```

Thank you.